# Overridding <a> tag click event to load data in its own <div>

Tags: json, jquery

I have an MVC grid which is rendered in  by a json call on page load.
On clicking any  tag of Grid I need to refresh this grid.
So I wrote this javascript.

```
$("#SearchGrid a").live("click", function (event) {
    var link = event.currentTarget.attributes[0].childNodes[0].wholeText;
    $("#SearchGrid").load(link);
    return (false);
});
```

Its working fine with IE9 and other browsers. But I need to make it workable on IE8.
In IE8 its not loading the grid in same div, instead it redirects it to a new page, containing just the grid which is return from json call.

Comment: Did you consider the chromeframe alternative? It allows transforming IE8 in a decent browser (http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It uses the attribute href directly instead of your IE proprietary code

```
$("#SearchGrid a").live("click", function () {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#SearchGrid').load(link);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @JeetendraTandel if this answered your question mark it as such with the green check mark. ;)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the problem might be, but here are some tips on debugging it:
 - var link = 'some-page.html'
try to see if you code actually returns any html data in IE8 - if it does then the problem lies in var link = event.currentTarget.attributes[0].childNodes[0].wholeText;
 - instead of load(), try to use an $.ajax call or a json call and see waht happens.
I hope these will prove useful

Comment: I think problem was with event argument that was passed in function. Because of it control didn't even went inside function body.

Comment: No, the problem was with your "wholeText" construct